# How to use topoJSON with D3

Tags: javascript, geojson, topojson, d3.js

I'm aiming to use topoJSON in my current D3 project due to its benefits over geoJSON such as greatly reduced file size. However, I've been a bit confused over how to accomplish this. My current thoughts after some research:

• Grab a shapefile from a source such as the [US Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html)

• Use D3's [topojson cli](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) to convert shapefile to topoJSON

• Use D3's [topojson client API](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference#client-api) to convert topoJSON file to geoJSON

Is this the correct approach?

(note: I am using D3 v4, not sure if there are any differences I should be aware of versus older versions of D3)

Comment: take a look at this : https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/